# Laravel 5 mail formatar html com css

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5, email

Estou enviando um e-mail através do `Mail` do laravel 5

```
$data = Input::all();
        Mail::send('mails.sendteste', $data, function ($message) {
            $message->from('sistema@sistema.com.br', 'Sistema');
            $message->subject('Teste');
            $message->to('meuemail@meuemail.com.br');

        });
```

Estou usando o código acima que carrega uma view que contém scripts CSS mas quando o e-mail chega pra mim, ele não lê o css e o e-mail fica todo sem formatação..

Tem alguma maneira de configurar os Headers como feito no php puro?

Obs: tentei usar o [Laravel Mail Css Inline](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner) mas não teve efeito algum.

Comment: Onde você esta abrindo os emails para testar? Esse site mostra suporte de css nos diferentes clients de email https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ e  link css segundo ele não é suportado no Gmail por exemplo.

Comment: @DanielBeff no Outlook 2013

Comment: Bem acredito que você tenha que alterar o template e colocar o css inline na view. O suporte a links externos nos clients de email é limitado. Então dê uma olhada em guias como esse https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ para saber o que os clients de email que você deseja dar suporte para adequar seu layout/view a eles.

Answer (score 2):

Dá uma olhada na documentação do lavarel https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Diz o seguinte:

**Mailing Plain Text
By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to the send method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition to the HTML view:
Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);
Or, if you only need to send a plain text e-mail, you may specify this using the text key in the array:
Mail::send(['text' => 'view'], $data, $callback);**

Ou seja, se quiser enviar o email no formato texto usa:

```
Mail::send(['text' => 'view'], $data, $callback);
```

No formato HTML usa

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'view'], $data, $callback);
```

Ou usa o formato automático

```
Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);
```